# Enabling/Disabling Network Adapter Property programmatically

Tags: batch-file, console

I'm just wondering, is there any way I can enable/disable a network adapter property using command line / batch file?

I would like to create a file that would toggle on/off any of these property of my network adapter.

[image: Adapter]

Answer (score 3):

On windows 10 you can check nmbind command (which looks like a supported port of nvspbind):

```
::disable
nmbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
nmbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
::enable
nmbind.exe /e "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
nmbind.exe /e "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
```

for older version check this:

You'll need [`nvspbind`](http://ss64.com/nt/nvspbind.html) - unsupported but irreplaceable.

Here's how to disable IPv6 and IPv4 for "Local Area Connection":

This for example should disable IPv6 on "Local Area Connection" :

```
nvspbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
nvspbind.exe /d "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
```

And this will enable them:

```
nvspbind.exe /e "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip6
nvspbind.exe /e "Local Area Connection" ms_tcpip
```

Here are all items on my machine for an lan connection:

> ms_netbios       (NetBIOS Interface)
>
> ms_server        (File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks)
>
> ms_ndiscap       (Microsoft NDIS Capture)
>
> ms_wfplwf_lower  (WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter)
>
> ms_wfplwf_upper  (WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter)
>
> ms_pacer         (QoS Packet Scheduler)
>
> sun_vboxnetflt   (VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver)
>
> ms_msclient      (Client for Microsoft Networks)
>
> ms_ndisuio       (NDIS Usermode I/O Protocol)
>
> ms_implat        (Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol)
>
> ms_lldp          (Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver)
>
> ms_lltdio        (Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver)
>
> ms_rspndr        (Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder)
>
> ms_pppoe         (Point to Point Protocol Over Ethernet)
>
> ms_rdma_ndk      (Microsoft RDMA - NDK)
>
> ms_tcpip6        (Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6))
>
> ms_netbt         (WINS Client(TCP/IP) Protocol)
>
> ms_tcpip         (Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4))
>
> vms_pp           (Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch)